# How to convert special characters to normal text when exporting to file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some input data from a website, that I have gathered using BeautifulSoup.
After I have collected the relevant information from the site, I want to export it to JSON.

This is what some of my output data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "time": "30\/3",
    "tag": "I\u00c3\u00b8"
  },
  {
    "time": "12\/4",
    "tag": "Da"
  }
]
```

It should be:

```
[
  {
    "time": "30/3",
    "tag": "Iø"
  },
  {
    "time": "12/4",
    "tag": "Da"
  }
]
```

Why does it look like that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know about the code around it, but this issue is because your code is trying to use ascii encoding, so it can't handle the special characters

to handle special characters with json you can just set `ensure_ascii` to false

```
import json

a = [
  {
    "time": "30/3",
    "tag": "Iø"
  },
  {
    "time": "12/4",
    "tag": "Da"
  }
]

print(json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "time": "30/3",
        "tag": "Iø"
    },
    {
        "time": "12/4",
        "tag": "Da"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is they're escaping the slashes and non-ASCII characters. One way is to use the `json` library like so:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = """[
...   {
...     "time": "30\/3",
...     "tag": "I\u00c3\u00b8"
...   },
...   {
...     "time": "12\/4",
...     "tag": "Da"
...   }
... ]"""
>>> json.loads(s)
[{'time': '30/3', 'tag': 'IÃ¸'}, {'time': '12/4', 'tag': 'Da'}]
```